# Use Future.successful(None) vs Future.failed(new Exception()) for an API that may return no results?

Tags: scala, future, api-design

What is the idiomatic  way in Scala to type an API that may or may not return results?
I can simply type to Future[Option[A]] and return a None if there is no results, but this will make things a little more verbose for API clients I think because it has to do some pattern matching (or other techniques like folding) over the Option returned.

```
trait SomeAPI {
  def fetch(): Future[Option[String]]
}

object APIImpl {

  def asyncDBCall(): Future[List[String]] = ???

  override def fetch(): Future[Option[String]] = asyncDBCall().map(r => if (r.isEmpty) None else Some(r.head)
}
```

However, Futures already give us a way to say that there are no results making it fail. But I don't know if this is a proper or expressive way of say that the call doesn't return results.

```
trait SomeAPI {
    def fetch(): Future[String]

}


class NoResultsException extends Exception

object APIImpl extends SomeAPI {

  def asyncDBCall(): Future[List[String]] = ???

  override def fetch(): Future[String] = asyncDBCall().map(r => if (r.isEmpty) throw new NoResultsException() else r.head)
}
```

At first it seems that both options are acceptable and the final decision may be just about personal preference, but maybe I'm missing something and make a Future fail is not a good option.

Comment: [Reactivemongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/find-documents.html) returns `Future[Option[T]]`. I guess that would be idiomatic Scala, instead of `null` use `Option`, `Either` or whatever suits you.

Answer (score 4):

Exceptions should be reserved for errors. If the API may or may not returns results, and both cases are considered normal, then the API should use `Option`.

If that makes it more verbose by forcing the client to handle both situations, that's good, because the client **should** handle both situations. Exceptions are good when you don't want to force the client code to handle an *exceptional* case (unexpected error) which should probably cascade and be handled by an error handler.

Now, if lack of results truly indicates that something went wrong, then an exception would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect clients want to treat "success, no results" and failure differently, generally speaking (e.g. retry in the second case, but not the first). If you denote the first with a failed future, you make verbosity for the clients *worse*, not better: they just need to check the exception instead of the success, and the API isn't helping them to be aware of that like `Future[Option[A]]` would.

If you really worry about verbosity, you could add custom extractors or methods for the clients to use if they want, e.g.

```
implicit class FutureOption[A](future: Future[Option[A]]) {
  def mapOpt[B](handleSuccessWithResult: A => B, handleSuccessWithNoResult: () => B) = Future.map {
    case Some(x) => onSuccessWithResult(x)
    case None => onSuccessWithNoResult()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The others are right. Failures are not a good way to describe the lack of a concrete result, if this is part of regular operation.

Scala gives you another possibility to explicitly note, that there may be no results, sealed traits.

```
sealed trait MyOperationReturn
case object OkNoResult
case class OkWithStringResponse(data: String) extends MyOperationReturn
case class OkWithIntResponse(data: Int) extends MyOperationReturn
```

The user can then just pattern match. This option is especially handy, if you have either multiple return types (not only two) and no natural empty return type (like `Seq.empty`)